# How to change arabic text alignment with polyglossia and memoir?

Tags: memoir, polyglossia, text-manipulation

I am trying to typeset a book which is completely in arabic. I am using memoir with polyglossia?

The result is fine, but the text is Fully Justified ?

How can i change the text alignment either through polyglossia, memoir or plain latex ?

Comment: `\raggedright`? `\raggedleft`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reach for the [ragged2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package when adjusting text alignment. While not all of its advantages are applicable to Arabic, it gets the job done.

In your preamble:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedLeft
```

You can change the indentation of the ragged left paragraphs with:

```
\setlength\RaggedLeftParindent{1.25em}
```